# Can't display images in picturebox in data repeater control in C#

Tags: c#

I can't display images  in picturebox in data repeater control.
my code is:

```
cnn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
bi.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text",bi,"Emri");
textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", bi, "Mbiemri");
Byte[] bfoto = (Byte[])(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Foto"]);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bfoto);
Bitmap bFoto = new Bitmap(ms);
pictureBox1.DataBindings.Add("image", bi, "Foto", true);

dataRepeater1.DataSource = bi;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image(v=vs.110).aspx) is an example of how to set image property from bitmap.

```
PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();
// your code
Bitmap bFoto = new Bitmap(ms);
pictureBox1.Image = bFoto;
```

Comment: thnx for answer, but i want to display a image in PictureBox in data repeater control.